# wagtail 2.0 beta 'wagtaildocuments.Document' has not been loaded yet

Tags: django, wagtail

I have installed the beta version of wagtail 2. Below is a code snippet from my project. When I try to makemigrations I get an error saying: 
**ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'link_document' yet, because its related model 'wagtaildocuments.Document' has not been loaded yet**

```
class LinkFields(models.Model):

    link_document = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtaildocuments.Document',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

    @property
    def link(self):
        return self.link_document.url


    panels = [
        DocumentChooserPanel('link_document'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class CarouselItem(LinkFields):
    embed_url = models.URLField("Embed URL", blank=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('embed_url'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
        MultiFieldPanel(LinkFields.panels, "Link"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I am using Django 2, Python 3.6, Wagtail 2.0b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Document model in your ForeignKey should be referenced as `'wagtaildocs.Document'`, not `'wagtaildocuments.Document'`.

While many of the module paths within Wagtail (as used in `import` lines, for example) have been updated for Wagtail 2.0, the app *labels* are unchanged. (It has to be done this way because the app label is just a single name like `wagtailimages` or `wagtaildocs`, with no dotted path to distinguish it: if it had been called `images` or `documents` instead, it would risk clashing with other apps in the project using that same name.) Model names within ForeignKey definitions are written as `'<app_label>.<ModelName>'`, so `wagtaildocs` is the correct name to use here.